# works locally, fails on Github Actions: can't transfer Github hosted parent pom, receives Bad Request an parent.relativePath points at wrong local POM

Tags: registry, pom.xml, github-actions, parent-pom

I'm at the moment building a project.
This project should use my [parent.pom](https://github.com/joergi/parent-jdk11-mongo/) from the [Github registry](https://github.com/joergi/parent-jdk11-mongo/packages/228373).

It works perfectly on my machine, even if I delete the parent-pom from my .m2 repository
Unfortunately, I always get an [error when Github tries to run the tests](https://github.com/joergi/basics/runs/1072139522#step:4:13) after each push, because the parent-pom can't be resolved.

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.joergi:basics:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not 
transfer artifact io.joergi:parent-jdk11-mongo:pom:2.3.0-1.RELEASE from/to github 
(https://maven.pkg.github.com/joergi/parent-jdk11-mongo): Transfer failed for 
https://maven.pkg.github.com/joergi/parent-jdk11-mongo/io/joergi/parent-jdk11-
mongo/2.3.0-1.RELEASE/parent-jdk11-mongo-2.3.0-1.RELEASE.pom 400 Bad Request and 
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
     @
```

The parent-pom has this definition:

```
<groupId>io.joergi</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-jdk11-mongo</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0-1.RELEASE</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>joergi.io parent-jdk11-mongo</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

My [new project](https://github.com/joergi/basics) use Github actions for automatic testing.
It integrates the parent pom like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>io.joergi</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-jdk11-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub joergi Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/joergi/parent-jdk11-mongo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I also have a [settings.xml](https://github.com/joergi/basics/blob/master/settings.xml) in the new project

```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub joergi Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/joergi/parent-jdk11-mongo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>joergi</username>
      <password>${{ secrets.PACKAGES_READ_ONLY }}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

The secret is in my Github secrets. If I remove or change it, I'm not authorized anymore, so this works.

Can one of you give me a hint, what is wrong

Comment: what do you mean by you are not authorized when you remove the secret? I tested this locally and on github actions and get the same error `400 Bad Request and 
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM`  but it's because i don't have the token permissions to download your parent pom so it seems expected. What error do you see when you remove the token? Per what i see so far, i'm curious if your token has permissions to download from your registry setup

Comment: interesting. Even if I now changed the token to xxx it was the same error.
But I also changed the token now to full github access (so I checked (only for try out) everything possible, it's still the same error.
I also have the problem, that the "token is never used"
so something is wrong there.
thanks for pointing me to this

Comment: You could also try passing the secret as env into your mvn command and changing the settings to use it as ${env.YOUR_TOLEN} I’m curious is secrets. has no way of being referenced properly within settings file

Comment: not sure if I have done it right...
https://github.com/joergi/basics/runs/1087885312?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:8
but I can't access it in the settings. or at least it's not working

Comment: Change <password>${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}</password> to <password>${ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }</password>

Comment: still not. (I chnged it to env.GITHUB_TOKEN but also to the name in my maven command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with the help of [github community user brightran](https://github.community/u/brightran) I was able to fix it, see the [post for more information](https://github.community/t/works-locally-but-on-github-actions-build-cant-transfer-own-github-hosted-parent-pom-receives-bad-request-and-parent-relativepath-points-at-wrong-local-pom/130983/5).

Somehow the password from the secrets in the settings.xml was not working, that why I go another way, as suggested.

in the maven deployment script I set a environment variable as you can see here:

```
- name: Publish to GitHub Packages
  run: mvn deploy -s settings.xml
  env:
    MVN_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

and in the settings.xml I read the variable, as you can see here.

```
<settings . . .>
  . . .
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>${MVN_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

this works now as expected.